# The ideal of the intersection of two algebraic subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $V, W$ are algebraic subsets of $\mathbb A^n(k)$. Show that $I(V∩W)=\sqrt{I(V)+I(W)}$

Answer (score 2):

Claim: $V(I(V)+I(W))=V \cap W$.

Prove the claim, and apply Hilbert's Nullstellensatz in the form $I(V(J)) = \sqrt{J}$ for every ideal $J$.

Comment: Thank you. To prove the Claim $V∩W⊂V(I(V)+I(W))$ follows by $V(I(V)+I(W))⊂V=V(I(V)$ the other side goes by the same way an the other one by definition.

Comment: @Miguel: I've merged your old account into your new one. I recommend that you register your account which will, among other things, allow you to accept answers and comment on your own questions and answers thereof.